# How do I use one element of an SVG to change the opacity of another, in the same SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am using an SVG code in an html file in order to animate certain elements. I have been successful with animating a specific path. However I want to now use one path to make another path smoothly change its opacity. I would like the second path to act as sort of a popup, being at 0 opacity when the page loads and then come in at 1 when I hover the mouse over another element. For example, the id of 1st element is Layer_11, the id of the second is bridgesandroadsgrades which is a box with text. Currently in my CSS, I have 
`#bridgesandroadsgrades {display: none
}`
to make it load without being visible.

I already have Layer_11 change color with hover using CSS. I can use javascript for which I use for other animations so I can use any script you could suggest for me. I will need any codes such as the any changes i would need to make to the html. I have already tried many codes and cannot get any to work. I have added a class to the html since much of what I have read so far either suggests this or creating a div.

element for rollover is

```
<g id="Layer_11" class="bridge1">
```

target is

```
<g id="bridgesandroadsgrades"  class="roadsgrades">
```

I would also like the element to fade out when the mouse is no longer hovering over Layer_11

Answer (score 0):

It's really pretty simple.  All you have to do is add mouseover and mouseout events to the first element and change the opacity of the other element.

The simplest way to have the opacity "smoothly change" is to change the class of the other element and use CSS `transition`.

```js
var Layer11 = document.getElementById("Layer_11");

Layer11.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
    var otherElement = document.getElementById("bridgesandroadsgrades");
    otherElement.setAttribute("class", "roadsgrades-on");
  });

Layer11.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
    var otherElement = document.getElementById("bridgesandroadsgrades");
    otherElement.setAttribute("class", "roadsgrades-off");
  });
```

```css
.roadsgrades-off {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.roadsgrades-on {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g id="Layer_11" class="bridge1">
     <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50"/>
  </g>

  <g id="bridgesandroadsgrades" class="roadsgrades-off">
     <circle cx="225" cy="75" r="50"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The only thing simple about this to me is that you are simply awesome. Thank you so much. You have no idea how much time I have wasted trying to research this. :)

Comment: Thanks. You are actually too kind :) YW

Answer (score 0):

It is simply possible with CSS element`+`element Selector.

```css
.bridge-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.bridge-1:hover + .bridge-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <g class="bridge-1">
    <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="50" />
  </g>
  <g class="bridge-2">
    <circle cx="225" cy="75" r="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```